# vector::push_back vs vector::operator[]

Tags: c++, stl, vector, operator-keyword, push-back

Below in `c++` program,

```
include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     vector<int> numbers;

    numbers.push_back(2);
    numbers.push_back(10);
    numbers.push_back(5);
    numbers.push_back(3);
    numbers.push_back(7);

    numbers[3] = 8;
    numbers[5] = 11;

    for(int i=0; i<numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
            cout<<" "<<numbers[i];
    }
}
```

see it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/lfx59).

here, `numbers[3]` is working but `numbers[5]`.
It looks like, vector::operator[] doesn't increase the size of vector like vector::push_back.
so, **is this the only difference between these two or something else is there**?

Comment: That is the difference. Why do you answer your question in the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`push_back` creates a new element on the back with the value specified. `operator[]` requires the element to be there; it just accesses it. The reason `[5]` doesn't work is because you have 5 elements, so your indices range from 0 to 4.

Generally, when adding new elements, `push_back` is preferred over `resize`, followed by `operator[]`. Only one can be used for reading, though, and `operator[]` is also needed to maintain normal array syntax.

Answer (score 14):

[std::vector::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at): "access specified element"

[std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back): "adds an element to the end"

I'm so amazing at looking at c++ references. You should try it.

Comment: Let's not confuse this with `std::map::operator[]`. cppreference.com: **Unlike** std::map::operator[], this operator **never inserts** a new element into the container. Accessing a nonexistent element through this operator is **undefined behavior**.