# Usage of vector push_back with pair

Tags: c++, vector

I was looking at the implementation of Prim's Algorithim on geeksforgeeks.org and tried to implement the function on practice mode. I looked at how the input was received and I saw this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 1e4 + 5;

int spanningTree(vector <pair<int,int> > g[], int n);

int main()
{
    int t ;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        vector <pair<int,int> > adj[MAX];
        int n,e;
        int w, mC;
        cin >> n>> e;
        for(int i = 0;i < e;++i)
        {
            int x,y;
            cin >> x >> y >> w;
            adj[x].push_back({w, y});
            adj[y].push_back({w, x});
        }

        mC= spanningTree(adj, MAX);
        cout << mC << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how they're using `vector`. I've never seen the passing of a vector in a similar way to an array: `vector <pair<int,int> > g[]`.

I looked at the STD implementation of `vector` and couldn't find anything about passing a vector this way, or constructing a vector with `vector <pair<int,int> > adj[MAX];`.

Lastly, I am very confused about what the following code does:

```
adj[x].push_back({w, y});
adj[y].push_back({w, x});
```

I tried implementing it myself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector< pair<string, int> > vec[2];
    vec[0].push_back({"One", 1});

    vec[1].push_back({"Two", 2});

    for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x){
        cout << vec[x].first << ", " << vec[x].second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I get an error `class 'std::vector< pair<string, int> >' has no member named ‘first’`.

If I could have some help understanding how `vector` is being used here, I would really appreciate it. I looked at multiple StackOverflow posts already, including [vector::push_back vs vector::operator[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007054/).

The link to the original problem is [here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/minimum-spanning-tree/1)

Comment: `vector <pair<int,int> > g[]` there's no passing of anything, it's just a declaration

Comment: This is simply an array of vectors. Plain C++ (C, really) data structure of array. Its elements are vectors.

Comment: It is an array of vectors and can be replaced with `vector<vector<pair<int,int>>` always remeber the [`spiral rule`](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) if you cant figure out what is being passed

Comment: @SamerTufail 1e4+5 is a _lot_ of nested vectors, though. Not ideal.

Comment: unrelated: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` are _*BAD*_ (tm). Look them up on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit absolutely but neither is declaring an array that huge, I dont think that many are required though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I completely agree. Not my code.

Comment: @YSC thanks for the pointer. Not my code. Would not have personally done that.

Comment: I would still encourage looking at the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) which is the crux of your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've never seen the passing of a vector in a similar way to an array: `vector <pair<int,int> > g[]`

It *is* an array! An array of vectors.

The problem with your code is that you have two vectors, both with a single element, and your loop only pulls out the vectors... not their single element.

Your version would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector< pair<string, int> > vec[2];
    vec[0].push_back({"One", 1});

    vec[1].push_back({"Two", 2});

    for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x){
        cout << vec[x][0].first << ", " << vec[x][0].second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

All I added was `[0]` (index into each vector).

Of course such an example is of questionable practicality. In such a situation it would seem that you want *one* vector with two elements, and no arrays in sight.

To be honest, I'm not wild about the original code, either. Mixing arrays and vectors is a recipe for confusion (*hyello*); they could have used "2D vectors" or, better, a 1D vector with 2D indexes laid on top of it. That would then have much better cache locality as well.

Comment: Thanks so much! Didn’t think that they would mix C-style arrays with vectors. This makes much more sense now. Will accept answer in 7 min.

Comment: why exactly 7 minutes?

Comment: @SamerTufail That was how many minutes remained before I could accept an answer :)

Comment: No rush - feel free to wait and see if anything better comes along ;)

Answer (score 3):

Its' a C-style array of vectors, really nothing magic here.

```
int spanningTree(vector <pair<int,int> > g[], int n);
```

Maybe you have seen something like that before:

```
int foo( int array[], int n);
```

In their code, the elements of the array are not `int`s but `std::vector`s. Why they mix plain arrays and `std::vector` I cannot tell you.

In your example, you need to first use `operator[]` to access an element before you can access its `.first` and `.second`, or use `front` to get the first element:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x){
    cout << vec[x].front().first << ", " << vec[x].front().second << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's may not be magic, but it's certainly ugly. Shame on them!