# Segmentation fault while working with 2D vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

May I know exactly why my code is getting segmentation faults whenever I start traversing or taking input into the 2D vector? I don't understand what is causing the problem. 
**Edit:** The `myvect[ans].push_back` is the part that's creating the problem. 
So my question is why doesn't it just push back and create a vector at the myvect[ans] position? Isn't that what a dynamic vector is supposed to do?
This is my code:

```
vector<vector<int>> myvect;
int ans = 2;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     myvect[ans].push_back(i+1);
     ans++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < myvect.size(); i++)
{
        if(!myvect[i].empty())
        {
            for(auto x: myvect[i])
                cout<<x<<" ";
        }
 }
```

Comment: where did you define `n` ?

Comment: It can be a user input ranging from 1 to 100

Comment: This is not a [mcve].  Where is `myvect` sized?  I see `myvect[ans]` show up, and we have no idea if that is a valid index into the vector.

Comment: I don't know the size of the vector before hand. I want its size to increase dynamically.

Comment: if you don't know the vector size, why did you hard code into 2 (`myvect[ans]`) ?

Comment: @AkramElectroTech If `myvect` is empty there is no element `myvect[ans];`.

Comment: So where are you changing the size of `myvect`?  That is probably the answer as to why you are having issues with your code.  Change `myvect[ans].push_back(blah);` to `myvect.at(ans).push_back(blah);` -- that will show the issue.

Comment: Ok, I realized that I haven't done enough research on 2d vectors. Could someone give me a link to where I can learn about dynamic operations on 2d vectors please!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the number of dimensions.  You have a `std::vector<T>`, and you failed to resize that vector.  It doesn't matter what `T` is -- in your case, `T` is a `std::vector<int>`, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: ```myvect[ans].push_back(blah);``` Done! Got a terminate after throwing out of range!

Comment: It's a dynamic array! why does't it just push back and create a vector at the myvect[ans]?

Comment: @AkramElectroTech: Because that would slow down correct code that doesn't need that handholding?

Comment: *"Isn't that what a dynamic vector is supposed to do?"* -- no, not in the C++ standard library. You're thinking of a different language (there are several that offer that functionality). When picking up a new language, sometimes "you must unlearn what you have learned." *To help your unlearning, see [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), in particular the "Notes" section..*

Comment: C++ is designed to be very fast, so it doesn't do any checks by default unless you ask it somehow, so that in the case when you're totally sure that there are no possible errors that code can be run as fast as possible and efficient. Only scripting languages like Python or JavaScript do a lot of checks on each step hence 100-200 times slower than C++ sometimes. If you want indexing to be checked everywhere use `myvect.at(ans)` instead of `myvect[ans]` everywhere, it will not resize by itself but still will through error that index is out of bounds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vector::push\_back vs vector::operator\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007054/vectorpush-back-vs-vectoroperator)

Comment: Yes! Now I get it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're indexing vector like `myvect[ans]`, but element with index `ans` may not exist, i.e. `myvect.size() <= ans`, C++ doesn't do bounds checking by default. Hence you have out-of-bounds segfault.

`C++` is designed to be super efficient and fast. Hence in every place of standard library if it is not asked by programmer explicitly C++ does no checks.

Only scriptable languages like Python or JavaScript do checking everywhere all the time, but this makes them sometimes 100-200 times slower than C++.

In `std::vector` there is a bounds-checking variant of indexing, you have to use `myvect.at(and)` which is identical to `myvect[ans]` but which throws exception if index is out of bounds. But don't forget to catch exceptions using `try-catch` syntax.

But still `.at()` method doesn't resize array automatically to add new elements. In order to have that functionality of auto resizing you have to implement that functionality yourself in your version of vector class.

Next I've coded my auto-resizing version. It also bounds check with exception by default on `[]` operator. You may extend any class from standard C++ library with any custom behaviour same way like I did for `std::vector` down below.

Output of next code:

```
Trying VectorT == "Vector<Vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<Vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >"
    use_at == true
1 2 3 
Trying VectorT == "Vector<Vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<Vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >"
    use_at == false
1 2 3 
Trying VectorT == "std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >"
    use_at == true
Exception: vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 2) >= this->size() (which is 0)
Trying VectorT == "std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >"
    use_at == false
exited, segmentation fault
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64084105#main.cpp)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef _MSC_VER
    // Only for Unix demangling
    #include <cxxabi.h>
#endif
using namespace std;

template < typename T, typename AllocatorT = typename std::vector<T>::allocator_type >
class Vector : public std::vector<T, AllocatorT> {
private:
    typedef std::vector<T, AllocatorT> SuperT;
    inline void FitSize(size_t i) {
        if (i > SuperT::size())
            SuperT::resize(i);
    }
public:
    template <typename ... Args>
    Vector(Args ... args) : SuperT(args ...) {}
    inline T & operator[] (size_t i) {
        FitSize(i + 1);
        return SuperT::operator[](i);
    }
    inline T const & operator[] (size_t i) const { return SuperT::at(i); }
    inline T & at(size_t i) {
        FitSize(i + 1);
        return SuperT::at(i);
    }
    inline T const & at(size_t i) const { return SuperT::at(i); }
};

// This function is just for informational purposes of demangling
char const * Demangle(char const * name) {
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
        return name;
    #else
        int status = 0;
        return abi::__cxa_demangle(name, 0, 0, &status);
    #endif
}

template <template < typename T, typename AllocatorT = typename std::vector<T>::allocator_type > class VectorT>
void Test(bool use_at) {
    try {
        VectorT< VectorT<int> > myvect;
        
        cout << "Trying VectorT == \"" << Demangle(typeid(myvect).name()) << "\"\n    use_at == " << (use_at ? "true" : "false") << endl;

        int ans = 2, n = 3;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (!use_at)
                myvect[ans].push_back(i+1);
            else
                myvect.at(ans).push_back(i+1);
            ans++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < myvect.size(); i++)
        {
            if(!myvect[i].empty())
            {
                for(auto x: myvect[i])
                    cout << x << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    } catch (exception const & ex) {
        cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
    } catch (...) {
        cerr << "Unknown Exception!" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    Test<Vector>(true);
    Test<Vector>(false);
    Test<vector>(true);
    Test<vector>(false);
    return 0;
}
```